# Video preview as soon as video file dropped at dropzonejs

Tags: jquery, dropzone.js

I am using dropzonejs to drop file and then upload to server. I would like to achieve when the video file is dropped, then it should be able to play using html5 video. Here is where I tried,

```
        this.on("addedfile", function(file, done) {
            var addedFile = jQuery(this.files[0].previewElement);
            if (file.type.match(/video.*/){
              engageVideo(addedFile)
            }
```

My plan(at engageVideo function) is to find the path of the file just added and use it to html5 video as a src. But in myDropzone instance of this file, I am not able to locate the url(path) of the file. Can I get help here ? Is there any better approach ?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like dropzone gives you a file list that you can work with as if it was a native `<input type="file"/>` FileList. You should be able to convert the file to an ObjectURL and assign it to a video player.

Assuming a `<video id="preview" controls autoplay></video>` tag in the HTML:

```
this.on("addedfile", function(file, done) {
   var $previewEl = $("video#preview");

   if ($previewEl[0].canPlayType(file.type) !== "no"){
      var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);

      $(previewEl).one('loadeddata', function(){
          URL.revokeObjectURL(fileURL);
      });
      previewEl[0].src = fileURL;
   }
})
```

Comment: This assumption you wrote above, "Assuming a <video id="preview" controls autoplay></video> tag in the HTML: .. " I can't find it anywhere.

Comment: @underScorePassionFruit Add the assumption to your html page